# getting specific info from openweathermap in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, urllib2, weather-api, openweathermap

I am trying to create a python program (as a university exercise) that will get coordinates from the user and print certain messages to the user eg:
if it rains at the certain region it will print "I am singing the rain"

```
import json,urllib2


while True:
    x=input("Give the longitude:")
    if x<=180 and x>=-180:
        x=str(x)
        break

while True:
    y=input("Give the latitude:")
    if y<=90 and y>=-90:
        y=str(y)
        break
url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+y+"&lon="+x+"&appid=01e7a487b0c262921260c09b84bdb456"
weatherbot=urllib2.urlopen(url)
weatherinfo=weatherbot.read()
```

So far I can get the info from Openweathermap,but if I try to get specific info like that:

```
currentweather=weatherinfo["weather"]["main"]
```

It gives me this error message:

```
TypeError:string indices must be integer, not str
```

Despite when I do:

```
print weatherinfo
```

it appears to be a dictionary.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

PS:Don't suggest installing extra libraries in Python,since I am not 100% sure our professor will be using said libraries to check our code.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment to me.

Answer (score 1):

`weatherinfo` is a JSON-formatted string. In order to have a dictionary like access to it, you need to load it via [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

```
import json

weatherinfo = json.load(weatherbot)
print(weatherinfo["weather"][0]["main"])  # prints "Clear"
```